# Open External Website/Address From Sencha Touch Application

Tags: javascript, iphone, url, sencha-touch

I have a ListPanel inside my application defined as follows:

```
            //Create List View Using ListStore Created in data.js
            SpotiPod.listPanel = new Ext.List({
                id: 'artistList',
                store: SpotiPod.ListStore,
                itemTpl: '<div>{ArtistName}</div>',
                grouped: true,
                indexBar: true,
                listeners: {
                    itemtap: function(list, index){
                        var rec = list.store.getAt(index)
                        //Ext.Msg.alert(rec.get('ArtistName'), 'Load In Spotify?', function(){location.href = rec.get('SpotifyURI');});
                        Ext.Msg.show({
                            title: rec.get('ArtistName'),
                            msg: 'Load In Spotify?',
                            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
                            fn: showSpotify
                            });
                        function showSpotify(btn){
                            if(btn == 'yes'){
                                window.open(rec.get('SpotifyURI'));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

The application presents a list of artists and should provide a link to them using the Spotify URI's, when you click yes to load spotify it should open the app and show the artist. The application as below works fine in the browser and in mobile safari on the iPhone. However if I add the application to the home screen and run it then it no longer works. I get an error that "The URL can't be shown."

Has anybody got any ideas on how this could be changed to allow the link to be fired correctly?

Cheers

Adam

Comment: What do u mean by adding the application to the homescreen?

Comment: As in I go the address of the web app in mobile safari i.e. mydomain.com/mywebapp and running the links to spotify from there will work and open the spotify app and load the correct information. If I select 'add to home screen' and have the app placed on my springboard then this stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I found on Sencha Forums, I do not know if it works so excuse me if it does not. The idea is to create an anchor markup and simulate a click on it instead of calling window.open() method. Here is the code doing this taken from sencha post.

```
Ext.util.openLink = function(href) { 
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', href);
  link.setAttribute('target','_blank');
  var clickevent = document.createEvent('Event');
  clickevent.initEvent('click', true, false);
  link.dispatchEvent(clickevent);
 return false;
}
```

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130358-window.open()-from-toolbar-button-opens-window-from-list-item-a-new-tab&p=639938#post639938